# On OS X, how do I log in interactively as root starting from my normal user account?

Tags: bash, osx, login, su, interactive

I have been doing this for a while:

```
sudo su -
```

but it uses 'sh' rather than 'bash', which is what I'd like to do.

Which command will log me in as root and get me a bash shell even if that's not the default the system gives me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sudo -i bash
```

Comment: You know it's interesting... your command sounds great if I read the "man page" but it does not go through my .profile (?!), using sudo bash -l does... but it keeps me in /Users/robottinosino rather than /var/root! Hmmm... any ideas?

Comment: @Robottinosino How are you determining that `.profile` is not read?  It is read for me, as it should.

Comment: Because .profile has side effects for me, like locking a file somewhere, and these are not triggered.

Comment: Just to make sure, this is root's profile you are talking about right?

Comment: $ grep root /etc/passwd (...) root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh but I learned this convention is not used on OS X? Something else is used instead (read: chsh)